# Hide status bar in windowmanager

Tags: android

Please,somebody,tell me how to hide/disable status/notification bar **using onlu`WindowManager`**, do not using `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN`, `AndroidManifest` or **something that is not `WindowManager`**.

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me, but i had to call the method every time i wanted to make sure the flag was like this

```
        anyViewInTheLayout.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I meant that answer must use only WindowManager.

Answer (score 1):

Put this line in your activity **onCreate()** method above **setContentView()** :

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Hope it help!

Comment: This flag won't work in android 4.1 and above but I need these APIs.

Answer (score 0):

use this as a style:

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but AFAIK you won't be able to set  style for the WindowManager. And I do need something that can work with WindowManager.

Answer (score 0):

You can put these code in your `onCreate()` method of your activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    } else { 
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();
    }
}
```

Hope it help!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I need code that uses only WindowManager. and it's flags.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programmatically like this:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide the status bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

More info on official pages: http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, your code uses **view** and it's SYSTEM_UI_FLAGs but I need a WindowManager.

Answer (score 0):

[FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)

As well as calculating the screen height, including the status bar

```kotlin
var resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android")
val statusBarHeight = if (resourceId > 0) {
    resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
} else {
    0
}
val params = object : WindowManager.LayoutParams() {
    init {
        width = MATCH_PARENT
        height = resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels + statusBarHeight
        type = TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
        format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        flags =
            FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE or FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL or FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN or FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
    }
}
```

[image]